# How to set _optimizer_search_limit and _optimizer_max_permutations in Oracle10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am working on a product that must support both MSSQL and Oracle (10g and 11g).  I have some very complex queries that seem to run without issue on MSSQL 2005/2008, but very, very slow with Oracle.  The CPU on the oracle server skyrockets for long periods of time, and it seems like the optimizer may be trying to find the best execution plan for the very complex query.  I did some Googling to figure out how to limit the amount of time the optimizer spends on this, and came up with _optimizer_search_limit and _optimizer_max_permutations.  Both of these parameters are hidden in Oracle 10g, and setting them in init.ora doesn't seem to make any difference.

How do I set these parameters in Oracle.

Or am I just totally barking up the wrong tree with the assumption that the optimizer is spending several minutes finding an execution plan?

Thanks.

Comment: `explain plan for your-precious-sql-statement;` see if running explian takes several minutes

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried this on a query that returns in a few seconds when using MSSQL and takes 2 hours with oracle.  The CPU on the server shoots to 100%, and it's been 15 minutes now with no execution plan returned.

Comment: You might want to move this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of a query taking 15 minutes to optimize.

First, I'd be checking the alert log. There may be some block corruption on a system table that is causing an issue.

Second, do you have stats gathered for all the tables being queried. 10g introduced dynamic sampling, by which the database will go look at the table for some stats if there are none in the data dictionary. If you have lots of very large tables, then gathering stats dynamically could be slow.

You can see if you've got (recent) stats with this

```
select table_name, last_analyzed from user_tables
```

If you are dealing with complex queries on large tables, then you should take some time to plan a stats gathering strategy.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug that could have been solved by now.
How many tables in the join?

You could do 10053 trace to figure out what's going on with CBO.

> ALTER SESSION SET TIMED_STATISTICS = TRUE;
>
> ALTER SESSION SET MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE = '2048M';
>
> ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE;
>
> ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = trace1_10053;
>
> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10053 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 1';

and then look in the trace file to check if your theory of CBO being stuck is valid. 12c has a limit of just 2000 _optimizer_max_permutations so it doesn't take a lot of time. In 10g-11g it used to be around 60k I believe.